# defining a time attribute in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, typescript, datetime, mongoose, nestjs

I'm currently building an e-learning application with NestJs and mongoose, and in one of my schemas I need to have a duration attribute that needs to be in the format of HH:mm.
Mongoose has no data type to store time. What is the best data type that should I use to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store it in two fields named *hours* and *minutes*.

```
new Schema({ 
   hours: Number,
   minutes: Number,
})
```

Or to be more precise you could store seconds in a *time* field and then convert it to *HH:MM* in your frontend.

```
new Schema({ 
   time: Number,
})
```

Comment: yeah, I've already come up with that solution, I was just asking is there any best way to do it. anyway, thanks for the tip.